# Ember data mutable array in hasMany relationship

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

So I have a model in my ember application that looks like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr("string"),
    highscore: DS.attr("number"),
    type: DS.attr("string"),
    choices: DS.hasMany("word-part"),
    usedChoices: DS.hasMany("word-part"),
    controller: DS.attr("string", {defaultValue: "activity"})
});
```

And I need to be able to pop items out of the `choices` array, but it seems it's not a mutable array. I've been looking over the docs and I can't find a way to have `choices` resolve as a `MutableArray`. Is there something I'm missing here? It appears the `choices` property of resolved models is readonly, so I can't even overwrite the entire array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `model` and `choice` and you know which choice, you would do this:

```
model.choices.removeObject(choice);
```

`hasMany` implements everything on [Ember.MutableArray](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html)